# BibTex can suddently not compile

Tags: bibtex

When I compile my document with `bibtex`, this is the error message:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit) The top-level
>   auxiliary file: thesiscoremathildev2.aux I found no \bibdata
>   command---while reading file thesiscoremathildev2.aux I found no
>   \bibstyle command---while reading file thesiscoremathildev2.aux (There
>   were 2 error messages)

```
 \documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter1}
\input{chap3/Motivation}
\input{chap3/Theory}
\input{chap3/MandM}
\input{chap3/Results}

@Article{Adato2013,
  author  = {Adato, Ronen and Altug, Hatice},
  title   = {In-situ ultra-sensitive infrared absorption spectroscopy of 
biomolecule interactions in real time with plasmonic nanoantennas},
  journal = {Nat. Commun.},
  year    = {2013},
  volume  = {4},
}


  \cite{Adato2013}

\bibliographystyle{nature_style}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

In my old tex file it works but not in the most recent one. I added the new chapter in the old tex file, but this still do not work ( I only added additional tables). And I tried: PDFLatex, Bibtex and two times PDFLatex.

Comment: try to `\cite{}` one of your sources.

Comment: for any \cite it is shown as"?" even if I compiled this file a 1000 times

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: Are you using some build folder or something else to redirect the auxiliary files? Do you have more than one version of `thesiscoremathildev.tex`? E.g. in a backup or dropbox?

Comment: The closing bracket of the bib-entry is missing.  Where can we get `nature_style.bst` from?

Comment: I added the missing }. But it does not help, this was just my mistake in this post. How can I add the nature_style.bst file?

Comment: @samcarter If the error message says that bibtex found no \bibstyle command then the content of the style is irrelevant. The question is why the info is not in the aux.

Comment: @Mathy Put XXXXXXXX directly before the \bibliography commands compile once and then check if the text appears in the pdf.

Comment: Actually, i reassembled my writing with a patchwork of old versions. But yes it´s not the best way to deal with the problem, I agree!

Answer (score 2):

Please copy the following MWE into a file `mwe.tex`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Adato2013,
  author  = {Adato, Ronen and Altug, Hatice},
  title   = {In-situ ultra-sensitive infrared absorption spectroscopy of 
             biomolecule interactions in real time with plasmonic 
             nanoantennas},
  journal = {Nat. Commun.},
  year    = {2013},
  volume  = {4},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{scrbook} 

\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}


\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter1}
text \cite{Adato2013} text

\bibliographystyle{plain} % nature_style
\bibliography{\jobname} % calls bib file created with filecontents!
\end{document}
```

Compile it with the cain

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
bibtex mwe
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

The MWE should compile with only one warning (okay, commes from package `filecontents`, only used to have TeX code and bib file in one MWE).

Now change the used bibliographys style `plain` to your used style `nature_style`.  Does it compile with only one warning? I can not test this, because I do not have this style and you gave us no link to it.

If it compiles, I guess you have your bib file `bibliography.bib` not in the same directory you have your `.tex` file.

If it does  not compile, please add the error message you get to your question.  Check the file `mwe.blg` too. If it contains error(s) add the file to your question too.

Comment: If I `\input` or `\include` a file that contains an `\end{document}`, that can cause this error, because of the duplicate `\end{document}` in the inputted or included file.